# What is CakePHP's bootstrap.php file?

Tags: php, cakephp

Does CakePHP's bootstrap.php file have to do anything with the [Bootstrap.js](http://getbootstrap.com/) framework?

Is there any specific reason behind this file being named as such?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstraps refer to a configuration file that includes the autoloader ( if present ) and any credential parsing/loading for a specific project.

The concept allows you to use a library in many projects only having to customize one file for each database/setup/modules to include/exclude.

Bootstrap framework was nicely named to suggest that using it will be synonymous to the bootstrap concept? ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is unrelated to the bootstrap framework.

The point is to provide a single point which, by design, allows the core app/configuration to be extended in a variety of ways, as suggested by:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#bootstrapping-cakephp

Code + comments in the bootstrap.php file maintained with the release provide guidance on specific uses. FWIW I find it convenient to include bootstrap.php in my version control repository, while excluding core, database & email configurations so they can be maintained separately on my development & production server(s).

Answer (score 0):

No, the two things are completely separate in all ways, other than their name.

**Bootstrap.js**
[Bootstrap.js](http://getbootstrap.com/) is a project, originally created by Twitter, to be a client-side development framework that encapsulates the workflow of HTML, CSS and JavaScript into an easy-to-use API. The project's tagline:

> Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.

I am not, personally, aware of the reasons why they named it 'Bootstrap' (it was originally named 'Twitter Blueprint', blueprint making a little more sense since it defines the structure and outline of your application).

**CakePHP's bootstrap.php**
CakePHP's `bootstrap.php` file, on the other hand, represents the actual term "bootstrap". Rather, the process of ["bootstrapping"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping). Because of this, the name `bootstrap.php` fits really well!

In general, bootstrapping is:

> the starting of a self-sustaining process that is supposed to proceed without external input

A better summary, keeping CakePHP in mind, is to say that the bootstrapping process in MVC applications (e.g. CakePHP) initializes "core" (i.e. used and available by everything in the application) configurations such as global constants, model / view / controller paths, or even loading other configuration files.

The [Configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html) documentation for CakePHP has several examples of how the application itself leverages `bootstrap.php` in this way (just search for "bootstrap.php" while on the page and you can jump through the examples). At the very bottom of that same page, you'll find a section on [Bootstrapping CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#bootstrapping-cakephp) which outlines several reasons you'd want to extend it yourself (a few of which I mention above) =]